# Reusing tabs in web browser

Tags: blackberry, browser

I am loading the given URL in web browser using the following code;

```
BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browserSession.displayPage(url);
```

Problem is, whenever I run this code, web browser opens the URL in a new tab (even if the URL is same). I want to reuse the existing tab or at least close the previously opened tab. In short I don't want to end up having a pile of tabs after firing several URLs.

Please guide me if there is any way to achieve this. I don't want to use `BrowserField`.

I am using;

- BlackBerry Eclipse JDE 1.5
- Target BlackBerry OS 4.5
- Tested on BlackBerry Bold 9900 on Wifi network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only one possible solution display pages inside your application by using `BrowserField` or `RenderingApplication`. There are samples available included to JDE or eclipse plugin.

Comment: Yes I know but my links are not supposed to be opened within my app,it must be on device browser.